# Making an express work with the express installed globally on windows

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have installed expressjs and nodemon i.e `npm install -g express` but i want the app i create `express the_app` to work with the modules that are installed globally.I can access npm on the command line so that part works.What should i do to use this globally installed modules?.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but you likely need to set

```
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
   NODE_PATH
     ':'-separated list of directories prefixed to the module search path.
```

set that variable to where npm installed modules globally.  This is needed at run time if not all of the modules (including your source) are installed in the same source tree.

Comment: Is there a difference between `npm install express -g` and `npm install -g express`?.

Comment: After trying it myself, no difference, though npm -g install _package_ is what is usually documented

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows,the globally installed modules are in this location `C:\Documents and Settings\Josef Doe\Application Data\npm\node_modules` by default.

Please copy that path(note that you have to enable view hidden folders) if you want to copy that path or if you know your username,just replace the `Josef Doe` username with yours.

After copying the path,right click on the computer after clicking the start button and head over to `enviromental variables`. While there identify the section called ***System variables*** and click the `New` button.

You shall be asked to add `variable name` and there you shall enter `NODE_PATH` and on the `variable value` section copy the global modules path you copied earlier.

Everything should work now.